# getting the relation data from where clause in view

Tags: eloquent

I have the following query

```
        $partner = DeliveryPartner::with(['deliveryPartnerImage' => function($q) {
        $q->where('image_type', '=', 'logo');
    }])
        ->find($id);
```

this works. for a partner with a logo it shows a relation with 1 item like so

[image]

and when i change the where clause to something non existent for example `$q->where('image_type', '=', 'testtesttest');`

it shows a empty array like this

[image]

so i know my query works but how to get this data in the view?

i did `$partner->deliveryPartnerImage()->first()` But for some reason this always shows data? also when i change the query... so im guessing im doing this wrong but i can not find another way to do this?

Comment: so when and where precisely  does your code fail?

Comment: in the view... it always shows data even when the realtion items is empty...

Comment: in your view you can check if you have items in your collection or not using [count](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-count) method. for example `@if($data->count()) // your have non empty collection @endif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```php
$partner->deliveryPartnerImage
```

`$partner->deliveryPartnerImage()->first()` executes a new query without the `where()` constraint.